# Which is the correct usage about act up?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Which is the correct usage of the verb *act up*?

1. Your wound has acted up.
2. Your wound acted up.
3. Your wound act up.

Comment: The first two are grammatical, the third one is not. And that has nothing to do with _act up_, but it is simply very basic English grammar: the third person singular present simple takes an _-s_, as in _your wound acts up_. With that correction, they are just three sentences with a different meaning, just like "I have eaten", "I ate" and "I eat".

Comment: I hear *My bunion is **playing me up*** more often than *My piles are **acting up***. (Well, not necessarily those specific complaints, obviously! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers You say 'obviously' as if we are all party to your detailed medical history. I'm afraid I am not- is knowledge of this a prerequisite for membership here? ;)

Comment: @Marv: No - I said I often *hear*, not *use*. The "obviously" was because people tend not to broadcast conditions like piles.

Comment: @FumbleFingers ah yeah missed that.. was only a little Thursday "humour" in any case :)

Comment: @Marv: I'm sure countless (well, I wouldn't want to count them) numbers of people will assure you that piles are no laughing matter! :)

Answer (score 1):

"I couldn't play golf Wednesday because my sciatica ***was acting up***, but on Tuesday, when it ***wasn't***, I shot a 96. My knee replacement ***is acting up*** today." (US)

Comment: As @Fumble Fingers's comments indicate, *playing up* is more common than *acting up* in Britain. But I believe they are synonymous. Though they lead to different inflections. For example in the UK you can say, as people often do, *My arthritis is playing me up*. You can't say *acting me up*! It is an interesting distinction, since in Britain it sort of conveys the idea that the *arthritis* has a mind, and is taking a perverse pleasure in the discomfort it is inflicting.